# failed to find file .pdf perhaps it has been deleted

Tags: bibtex, texstudio

i'm looking for a solution to this the whole day and i couldn't find.
When i "Build and View" my document, in the view i recieve the message failed to find file Thesis.pdf` perhaps it has been deleted, and thesis is my document. Moreover i get on bibtex log file "The top-level auxiliary file: Thesis.aux

```
A level-1 auxiliary file: preface.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Thesis.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Thesis.aux
(There were 2 error messages)"
and
"Citation `xxx' on page y undefined".
```

i've tried run first the latex, than bibtex, than latex and latex again. But this didnt work.

When i start running the latex and stop in the middle of the compilation i get a pdf file on the computer, but when i let the compilation run without interruption the .pdf file disapear!

In the `option-> configurations-> command-> pdflatex` I have the command:

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

and I'm running the texstudio 2.8.4 and I tried to do this on miktex but it doesn't generate the pdf.

Until yesterday I didn't have this problem and i don't know what to do!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Try compiling at the command line. (You don't want it in non-stop mode. You want it in stop mode so you can figure out where the problem is.) And/or read the log file generated by the latex run.

Comment: I suggest two strategies. First, examine the logs for error messages. It could be that at first the PDF is being generated then a subsequent error results in its deletion. Also, look at what's changed between the two versions, use `diff` or similar to narrow down where the issue might be. Don't forget to check ancillary files like your bibtex database, since the error may not be in the main file.

Comment: I've just edited your post. Backticks `\`` are used to highlight code so you have to escape then using `\``\'` if you want to insert them in your text.

Comment: Save the `thesis.tex` with a new name in a new directory and compile again.

Comment: The log file only highlight the "Citation 'xxx' on page y undefined" error. I tried to change the `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` to `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}` and `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` but nothing changed.
I`ll try to use diff and to change the name of thesis.tex!